# How to require required files in WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, require

I am writing a WordPress plugin that is to make several classes available to sites that have this plugin installed, but I want to define these classes each in their own file, without forcing the theme author to require each file separately.  Is there a way to do this?  So the theme author should be able to install the plugin and then have access to the classes without using require, and the classes should each be defined in their own separate files.

Addendum: This is not a WordPress-specific question; it applies to php generally.  WordPress is just the current context.  To rephrase it in a framework-agnostic way, if I have files A, B, and C, how can I fiddle with the relationship between A and B such that C can require A and get access to the classes in B without C requiring B directly?

Comment: A WordPress plugin is just plain old PHP, you can require/include files just like you would normally do, nothing special needs to be done.

Comment: The problem is that, if I require all the separate files for the separate classes in the main plugin file, php does not act as if those classes were defined in the main plugin file, so when I try to use them in the theme, they aren't defined.  I could have the theme files require the individual class files directly, but that is what I am trying to avoid.  So yes, this problem isn't specific to WordPress; that is just a bit of context.

Comment: To rephrase, if I have files A, B, and C, how can I fiddle with the relationship between A and B such that C can require A and get access to the classes in B without C requiring B directly?

Comment: I usually use an autoloader in my plugins, and watch for classes in my dedicated namespace to `require`, that way they are only loaded when needed. But no matter what, you want to make sure that you aren't using hooks for this, because that could be too late. In the theme, as long as WordPress has booted properly (someone isn't using SHORTINIT or other tricks), those classes should all be available.

Comment: I beleive you should ask this question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky This is not a WordPress-specific question; that is just the surrounding context.  It is for php generally.

Comment: Just use an [autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). There's many examples out there for specific implementations, but the idea is that you map classes to files. PHP will take care of "this class isn't loaded, let's see if the autoloader can help me" automatically. Once you have your autoloader set, you don't have to think about including specific files, it is all taken care of for you. Class `C` doesn't get access to `B` through `A`, there are just global classes now for all code to use.